# Simple SQL Query takes 10-20 times more with "ORDER BY"

Tags: mysql, wordpress, performance, sql-order-by, query-optimization

Simple SQL query takes 10 to 20 times longer with "ORDER BY". How can I speed it up?

My first query was:

```
SELECT * 
FROM wp_usermeta 
WHERE meta_key = 'partner' 
AND meta_value = 1 
ORDER BY user_id DESC
LIMIT 5
```

It takes 0.2601 seconds. After some research I could optimize it to:

```
SELECT user_id 
FROM wp_usermeta 
WHERE meta_key = 'partner' 
AND meta_value = '1' 
ORDER BY umeta_id DESC
LIMIT 5
```

This query takes just 0.1491 seconds, but still too much. If I remove the ORDER BY, it takes only 0.0075 seconds.

I read a lot on Stackoverflow and other forums, but I could not get a better output. Has someone an idea?

It is a standard WordPress usermeta table.

Comment: As well as SHOW CREATE TABLE statements  for all relevant tables, questions about query performance always require the EXPLAIN for the given query

Comment: Yes, you should always include the table definition in a query optimization question, but `wp_usermeta` is a pretty recognizable table in a WordPress database.

Comment: @billkarwin it's beside the point

Answer (score 1):

The wp_usermeta table in WordPress is well-known and it has a single-column index on `meta_key`.

But this selects *all* rows with the specified key, which doesn't narrow down the search much. Also it doesn't help sorting, so the query must do extra work to do the sorting:

```
mysql> explain SELECT *  FROM wp_usermeta WHERE meta_key = 'partner'  AND meta_value = 1  ORDER BY user_id DESC LIMIT 5\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: wp_usermeta
         type: ref
possible_keys: meta_key
          key: meta_key
      key_len: 767
          ref: const
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using where; Using filesort
```

Adding a new index should help:

```
mysql> alter table wp_usermeta add key (meta_key(191), meta_value(191), user_id);

mysql> explain SELECT *  FROM wp_usermeta WHERE meta_key = 'partner'  AND meta_value = 1  ORDER BY user_id DESC LIMIT 5\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: wp_usermeta
         type: ref
possible_keys: meta_key_2,meta_key
          key: meta_key_2
      key_len: 767
          ref: const
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using where; Using filesort
```

Even though this shows it's using the new index (`meta_key_2`), it's not helping. The `key_len` and `ref` indicate it's only using the first column of the index. Why can't it use both columns?

Because your query compares the integer value `1` to a string column `meta_value`. You must compare similar types, i.e. string `'1'` to the string column:

```
mysql> explain SELECT *  FROM wp_usermeta WHERE meta_key = 'partner'  AND meta_value = '1'  ORDER BY user_id DESC LIMIT 5\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: wp_usermeta
         type: ref
possible_keys: meta_key_2,meta_key
          key: meta_key_2
      key_len: 1534
          ref: const,const
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using where
```

Now it's able to use the second column in the index to search for value `'1'`, you can tell because `key_len: 1534` and `ref: const,const` indicate it's using two columns of the index instead of one column.

Then the optimizer realizes it's already reading the data in order by `user_id`, so there's no need to sort. The "Using filesort" goes away.

Comment: In most situations, prefix indexes do not work.  Nothing past the first prefix is looked at.

Answer (score 0):

WP has an inefficient schema for its "meta" tables.  But they can be fixed.  In [*here*], I discuss several things that need fixing.  And I explain the 191 kludge, plus 5 options for avoiding it.

And I don't get into "index merge intersect", since a composite index is always(?) better.